# django: value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: python, django, date

I have a question
I use xpath to get  `item['releaseday']` from website.
When xpath didn't get value

It will cause error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: [u"'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

in my models.py I set null=True and blank=True seems like not work

```
releaseday      = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
```

I try add this code,but not work

```
    if 'releaseday' not in item:
        item['releaseday']=''
```

How can I edit???
Please guide me thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `item.get('releaseday') or None`.

You'll solve two problems:

1. When the key does not exist, this will default to `None`, which is valid input for your model as you have `null=True`.
2. If the key exists but its blank `''`, then it will result in `None` which is a valid value for your model.